# Como asignar un objeto en sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Quisera que me  ayudaran en esta duda:

Como puedo asignar un valor "mayor que" o "menor que" a un objeto en SQL Server?

Un ejemplo de lo que mas o menos quiero lograr:

```
DECLARE @Pregunta AS INT > 3
PRINT @Pregunta
```

Esto me da incorrecto, puesto a que solo me permite asignar valores unicos. Hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Comment: Pero para que te serviria o como piensas usarlo? podrias validarlo pero no se cual es tu objetivo o para que lo pretendes usar?

Comment: No existe lo que pides. Sospecho que estamos ante un [problema xy](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/21). Creo que vendría bien que expliques cuál es tu problema original, pues es más probable que encuentres ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué esperas que contenga la variable? No es claro tu ejemplo